# ros-jade-desktop-full and ros-kinetic-desktop-full are out of reach

Tags: ros, desktop-full

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed those packages dozen of times.... Yesterday, I had to install a new machine and got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-desktop-full
```

Is there a problem somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265447/ros-jade-desktop-full-and-ros-kinetic-desktop-full-are-out-of-reach/) by [mhallak](https://answers.ros.org/users/3537/mhallak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well .. which OS are you running, and more specifically, which version?

ROS Jade packages are basically only available for Ubuntu Trusty (14.04), not for Xenial (16.04) or anything later.

ROS Kinetic is available only on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) .

See also [REP-003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) (the REP still states that 14.10, 15.04 and 15.10 are also supported, but afaik no packages are being built for those distributions any more.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0